# Can't install Xubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: system-installation

I am attempting to install Xubuntu 20.04 LTS on VirtualBox 6.0 on my Windows 10 Pro machine, but I'm having a problem. When I try to run the virtual machine so I can install it, I am shown this:

[image: screenshot]

Would anyone know what might have caused this issue?

Comment: Does it stuck on that screen ?

Comment: Have you verified your ISO ? It's the grub screen in ubuntu live. Seems it got stuck in the grub stage. So the ISO might be corrupted. And also have you given it enough [resources](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) ?